# Can't get coordinates from CLLocationManager in separate variable/constant

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-location

I'm trying to set a variable/constant in Swift using a value from a function which finds the user's current location whilst the app is open. When I uncomment the print function it successfully prints the coordinates but I can't access the value outside of the function.

I currently have this as a part of my code which is in the MainVC.swift file as part of the MainVC class:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MainVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    //Map
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    let coordinates = locationManager()
    //I've also tried using let coordinates = currentCoords

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) -> String {
        let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        lat = String(myLocation.latitude)
        long = String(myLocation.longitude)
        let currentCoords:String = "\(lat);\(long)"

        //print(currentCoords)
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

        return currentCoords
    }
}
```

However I'm faced with this error:

> "Cannot use instance member 'locationManager' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".

When I change the code and use

```
let coordinates = currentCoords
```

I get another error showing:

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'currentCoords'"

I have also tried using a lazy var and lazy let.

Comment: You need to provide a little more context for the code you posted.

Comment: Isn't your error from your initializer? paste code from your **initializer** where you get the error.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry about that, forgot to add it when originally posting, updated the main post with a bit of context hopefully that helps.

Comment: Post the entire function that contains the code you posted. Note that "coordinates" is a horrible name for an instance of the location manager.

Comment: @DuncanC that is the whole function, I used a different identifier in the app I just changed it when posting for readability. I've added some more info to the original post which will hopefully help.

Comment: `let coordinates = locationManager()` <-- this is inside what **bigger** function? It can't be just sitting there. You haven't pasted your whole function

Comment: @Honey Apologies, I've added the rest of the code so far, sorry if I am getting irritating too!

Comment: Your `lat`, `long` need a `let` or `var` before them.

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `let coordinates = locationManager()
`? What class is `locationManager`??...I maybe guessing too much here but I feel like you could start with a smaller project and then slowly jump into bigger projects. Take your time. We have all been there.

Comment: @Honey I'm using it to try and pull the value of the returned currentCoordinates from my locationManager function and set it as a variable outside of the function, I have a feeling I'm doing it completely wrong though.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the asynchronous nature of location services.  Once you request location, you need to wait until the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method is called.  You can't simply access location immediately

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah, I did not know that, is there a way that I can grab the location upon the app start only and save it as a variable as to not change the value every second?

Comment: If you are targetting iOS9 and later then you can use `requestLocation` to get a one-shot location https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation It still calls the `didUpdateLocations` method asynchronously since obtaining location may take some time, but it will only call it once

Comment: @Paulw11 is there a way I could quickly implement this into my current code without having to change much?

Comment: You need to change the signature of your `didUpdateLocations` method so that it matches the required signature (it is a Void return, not a string) and then you will need to handle the fact that the location is delivered asynchronously, either by using a callback closure or just putting your required code in `didUpdateLocations`

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to access locationManager.location?.coordinate as in my buttonClick method :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate
        let lat:Double = (location?.latitude)!
        let lon:Double = (location?.longitude)!
        print(lat,lon)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidAppear")
        // status is not determined
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
            // authorization were denied
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
            showAlert("Location services were previously denied. Please enable location services for this app in Settings.")
        }
            // we do have authorization
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("didUpdateLocations")
        print(locations.last?.coordinate)
    }

    func showAlert(_ title: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. I tried to do it this way but for some reason it doesn't like that method ether, I'll post the error I get with that method as soon as I get on my MacBook tomorrow.

Comment: I get the following error: Value of type '(MainVC) -> (CLLocationManager, [CLLocation]) -> String' has no member 'location'

Comment: I get it on the `let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate` line

Comment: Are you using swift 3.0 ?

Comment: I should be, using Xcode 8 and deployment target was set to iOS 10

Comment: Have you added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription with a string to your info.plist file ?

Comment: I've got `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` as to not use location data whilst the app is closed, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define your public variable

```
let coordinates:CLLocation = nil
```

Then in your didUpdateLocations assign the coordinates variable with last element of locations array. Then you'll have access to it everywhere.
Keep in mind didUpdateLocations may be called even up to a few seconds later so your public variable coordinates will be populated after may be up to a few seconds or so.

```
func coordinatesBecomeAvailable() {
    // Here you can print your coordinates or start using them for the first time
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
 let firstTime:Bool = (coordinates == nil)
 coordinates = locations[0]
 if (firstTime) // This is first time this function is called
     coordinatesBecomeAvailable()
 ......
 < Rest of your code here >
 ......
 < This function does have any return value! no String nothing >
 }
```

You just need to check whether the value of coordinates is nil or not.
Or you can check inside the didUpdateLocations whether this is the first time this delegate method is called.
This is not the most efficient and completed way of initializing and using location manager and I assume you just posted the code related to your problem.

Comment: I changed my code and added this but when I print coordinates it shows nil

Comment: I changed the code so you know when to print the coordinates when they become available.

Comment: @robycyr for some reason I'm still getting nil 

Comment: I changed the didUpdateLocations function and replaced "locations.last" into "locations[0]" like your code, now you can put a break point in that line of code and step through in the debug mode one line of code at a time and see if the "coordinates" gets the value or not. From this point on is the matter of debugging. And you use the "coordinatesBecomeAvailable" function to print or use your first usage of the variable.